# Terraform, can you use for_each to create X amount of resources?

Tags: foreach, terraform, azure-virtual-network, terraform-provider-azure, subnet

I am working on trying to have a Virtual Network create "X" amount of subnets based on a .tfvars file passing in the correct number of subnets (might be a little complex).

For example, if I want the same code in my main.tf that creates a VNET/Subnets to be used over and over in different environments, I could run the main.tf with a different "xyz.tfstate" file and just pass in different variables into different tfvars files.

Say, I have 3 environments:

1. Environment A - (EnvA.tfstate, EnvA.tfvars)
2. Environment B - (EnvB.tfstate, EnvB.tfvars)
3. Environment C - (EnvC.tfstate, EnvC.tfvars)

So I have 3 .tfstate files, and 3 different .tfvars files. The 3 different .tfvars files will pass in the subnets that they want to create. For EnvA = 3 subnets, EnvB = 10 subnets, EnvC = 20 subnets. Is there a way to do a for_each to take in variables to create the # of subnets I want? Or is there some way to pass in "X" amount of subnets into the resource using maps or something like that?

I don't want the main.tf to take in any specific information about the environments other than what is passed in as a variable from the .tfvars files.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's exactly the purpose of `for_each` in terraform. You can have a variable called `cidr_block` and pass list of cidr blocks for each environment via variable file. In `main.tf` you can add block similar to this:

```
resource "aws_subnet" "subnets" {
  for_each   = var.cidr_block
  vpc_id     = aws_vpc.main.id
  cidr_block = each.value
}
```